# expressjs and angularjs routing issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I've started building my own and I have an issue which I pretty much spent whole day trying to fix.

Basically, I'm using angular $resource to communicate to my API.

All my routes (jade templates) are working and rendering properly but here comes the problem.

I'm currently building my blog system where I have so far created a simple CRUD.
I'm adding posts to my blog via form and I can access each post by it's ID (using mongodb and mongoose), so I simply click on the title and separate page opens for my post.

The only problem that I'm experiencing is when I refresh the page /:id one.

Then my default style is lost and I only get an object in return. (my mongoDB object).

Here is some of the code:

ExpressJS get method:

```
module.exports.getSinglePost = function(req,res) {
    Posts.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data) {
       if (err) { 
          res.send(err); } 
       else {
          res.json(data)
       }
})
```

Angular JS route

```
.when('/bblog/posts/:id', { 
   templateUrl: 'views/post', 
   controller: 'singlePostController' 
})
```

Express JS routes

```
router.route('/bblog/posts/:id') // get single id
      .get(CRUD.getSinglePost)
      .put(CRUD.updatePost)
      .delete(CRUD.DeletePost)

router.route('/views/*')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.render(req.params['0']);
});

router.route('*')
  .get(function(req, res) {
      res.render('index');
});
```

So basically for me everything works normal now until I refresh the page with params /:id (params), then it just prints out entire object on blank white page (when I for example refresh `localhost:3000/bblog/posts/54641972b7557ecb6e637aa6`, which is one of the posts I have)

example:

```
{
  "_id":"54641972b7557ecb6e637aa6",
  "content":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishin\",
  \n\"title\": \"orem Ipsum is simpl","title":"orem Ipsum is simpl",
  "__v":0
}
```

**HINT**
When I put this route below catch all route (*) then I can refresh the page but the problem is that I don't get json element in return any longer but html page without my object etc.

```
router.route('/bblog/posts/:id') // get single id
  .get(CRUD.getSinglePost)
  .put(CRUD.updatePost)
  .delete(CRUD.DeletePost)
```

As usual, thanks a lot in advance and I hope your awesomeness can help me fix this strange issue :).
Cheers

Comment: Let me get this straight. Do you have a correct layout with url 'localhost:3000/bblog/posts/54641972b7557ecb6e637aa6' at some point? That would seem strange to me.

Comment: I access my posts by providing id of my mongodb posts. Each post has its unique id.This work just fine, only problem is when zi refresh any post, then my post.jade template just doesn't render.

Comment: So you can navigate to the blog post page through the Angular app but when you reload the browser, the server sends you the data endpoint instead? Are you using html5 mode true, any hashPrefix setting in app.config() or base url in index? It seems like your server is hijacking the route to your angular page that matches the database page. Perhaps you want your db endpoint to have a similar but different address than the routing in Angular.

Comment: Yeah, I have a base URL in my index. jade set to / and it's exactly like you said. When I visit some post for the first time, page renders just normally but whatsoever if I refresh that page, all my partial is gone and instead of that, I just get the data from the API and no more render. Pretty much something similar to problem many people had with refreshing the page and then they've been told to create catch all route to fix this. Also, when I put this route below catch all route, then I can refresh the page but I don't get json file anymore from API but the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Just as user:  irth stated, only thing I had to do is change the resource path and expressJS route to something else. This works now but whatsoever, I have no clue now. It seams this is one of those days when you are like "Oh my code doesn't work, I don't know why, my code works, I don't know why".

Thanks a lot user irth. Not sure why your answer is not shown so I can give you credits etc.